# Qt/QML - How to apply the same background to all DelegateChioces in DelegateChooser?

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols2, qtdeclarative

Hi I have a `DelegateChooser` for a `TableView` with 10-20 different `DelegateChoice`s. How can I apply **the same** background to all the choices? I want to avoid having to add the same background to all choices as that is a lot of repeater code and a maintenance headache:

```
DelegateChoice: {
   Item {
         Rectangle { id: background; anchors.fill: parent; color: "blue" }
         Choice1 {}
    }
    ...
   Item {
         Rectangle { id: background; anchors.fill: parent; color: "blue" }
         Choice20 {}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the `Item`s in your example do not serve a purpose - `Rectangle`s are `Item`s, only colored instead of transparent, making the top level `Item` a duplicate. Secondly, I would just make a new file `MyBackground.qml` as such:

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Rectangle {
    color: "blue"
    // any other necessary background properties here
}
```

Then you make your `ChoiceN` files inherit from `MyBackground`, for example:

```
// ChoiceN.qml file
import QtQuick 2.0

MyBackground  {
    // ChoiceN.qml contents here as normal
}
```

And your example code becomes:

```
DelegateChoice: {
    Choice1 {}
    ...
    Choice20 {}
}
```

Alternately, if you do not have access to your ChoiceN file contents, you can encapsulate them from outside as well:

```
DelegateChoice: {
    MyBackground {
        Choice1 {}
    }
    ...
    MyBackground {
        Choice20 {}
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. The only thing I don't like about this answer is that it makes my Choices non-reusable. I would rather keep my delegates as self contained reusable files and it does not make sense for reusable components to have set background.

Comment: But this seems like the best solution given the limitation of DelegateChooser. I would have preferred to somehow add the background to every delegate at once.